# Should awakened mind be considered an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

Should awakened mind be considered an action? I need to know because in combat I want to use it to talk to my team without alerting enemies to our presence.

Comment: Are you asking if Awaken Mind should be changed to take an action or whether the rules currently say it takes an action?

Comment: Does that Q&A linked above answer your question? If not, please [edit] your question to indicate how it is different.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose fwiw, I think the use of "should" is merely phrasing. I believe he / she meant the latter, which is why I voted to close the question as a duplicate. Until the OP clarifies whether he meant something else, I believe closing the question is the correct course of action.

Comment: @PixelMaster agreed! It was a good call and good catch. The only reason I asked was to be absolutely clear about what they meant in the slight chance they were asking it the other way.

Comment: @NEWB I'd question your implication that just because something takes an action that it would be obvious (or potentially obvious) to others. Even if Awakened Mind DID take an action, there is no reason that it would be perceptible to anyone not involved in the communication.

Answer (score 4):

## Speaking with Awakened Mind does not take an action

> You can telepathically speak to any  creature you can see within 30 feet of you.

Nothing in the Awakened Mind feature says anything about it taking an action, so it doesn't take an action. This fits in with the default rules for speaking which also doesn't take an action.

> You can communicate **however you are able**, through brief utterances and gestures, as you take your turn.

This ability simply allows you to speak in a telepathic way and doesn't otherwise change the action economy of doing so.